# Android app not receiving firebase notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

My android app is not receiving any firebase notification. When I send a message from the firebase console it is showing that the process is completed and when the row is expanded it shows 0 message send, screenshot below

[image: Screenshot]

Expiry of the message is set to 1 minute.

I've added the `FirebaseMessagingService` , `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and added the services in the manifest like this

```
    <service android:name=".service.TjssFireBaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".service.TjssFireBaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I've tried adding

```
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true"
```

This is the `onCreate` method of application class

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mGlide = Glide.with(this);

    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    if (token != null)
        M.log("Firebase Token", token);
}
```

and I've a valid token in the logcat output

I did everything they said the documentation, but it is not working. Did I miss something important?

Comment: share your complete manifesh and Application file,, have you initialized FirebaseInstance in Application file?

Comment: I've edited my question and added `onCreate` of the application class. And How to initialize Firebase instance?

Answer (score 1):

In your onCreate of Application add this

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

this meaning context here

Answer (score 0):

have you put `google-services.json` in your app folder ? . if not please put it in app folder  and look information in this file it is relavant to your project or not . Try to send notification by selecting your application package name . I hope this will work. Thanks

Comment: please check your package name in that

Comment: Copied the package from the manifest into the firebase console

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your app is not running when you are sending the notification. If your app is in the foreground then you won't be able to receive notifications.

If you want to receive notifications when your app is in foreground, edit your service as follow:

```
public class TjssFireBaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Val", remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDeletedMessages() {
    super.onDeletedMessages();
}}
```

The above code will start your main activity when a notification is received and your app is in foreground.